# Pygame Key Constants not defined

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I try to add keyboard input in my game, it says `K_SPACE` or `K_<ANYKEY>` not defined whenever I press something on the keyboard.

I tried to use other keys, but it doesn't solve the issue, instead giving me `K_<OTHERKEY>` not defined. I am developing on the Raspberry Pi. What can I do to fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

currentlyRunning = True

pygame.init()
mainScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 1024), pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE)
pygame.display.set_caption("PiPong")
pixelSizeX = 20
pixelSizeY = 16
pixelSize = [pixelSizeX, pixelSizeY]
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (104, 255, 142)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pongStart = False
pongPlay = False

def pixelRasterize(pixelMultiplier, xy):
    if xy == True:
        return pixelMultiplier * (1280 / 20)
    else:
        return pixelMultiplier * (1024 / 16)

def characterRender(character, color, carX, carY):
    if character == "A":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, True)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, True)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, True)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "a":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(.5, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(6, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1.5, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(4, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "B":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(1.5, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(2, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1.5, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(2, False)])
    elif character == "b":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
    elif character == "C":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "c":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "D":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(2, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(2, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "d":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "E":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
    elif character == "e":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, False)])
    elif character == "F":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
    elif character == "f":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, False)])
    elif character == "G":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(7, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    elif character == "g":
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) - pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(3, False), pixelRasterize(5, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) - pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(3, False)])
        mainScreen.fill(color, rect=[pixelRasterize(carX, True) + pixelRasterize(2, True), pixelRasterize(carY, False) + pixelRasterize(1, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, False)])

while currentlyRunning:
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            currentlyRunning = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                if pongPlay == False:
                    pongStart = True
            if event.key == K_W:
                pMoveOne = 1
            elif event.key == K_S:
                pMoveOne = 2
            else:
                pMoveOne = 3
            if event.key == K_UP:
                pMoveTwo = 1
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                pMoveTwo = 2
            else:
                pMoveTwo = 3
    mainScreen.fill(BACKGROUNDCOLOR)
    if pongStart == True:
        ponger = random.randint(1, 64)
        pOne = 32
        pTwo = 32
        pOneP = 0
        pTwoP = 0
        pBall = 32
        pProgress = 0
        pMove = False
        pongStart = False
        pongPlay = True
    if pongPlay == True:
        if pongMoveOne == 1:
            pOne -= 1
        elif pongMoveOne == 2:
            pOne += 1
        if pongMoveTwo == 1:
            pTwo -= 1
        elif pongMoveTwo == 2:
            pTwo += 1
        if pMove == False:
            pProgress += 1
            if pBall != ponger:
                if pBall < ponger:
                    pBall += 1
                else:
                    pBall -= 1
        elif pMove == True:
            pProgress -= 1
            if pBall != ponger:
                if pBall < ponger:
                    pBall += 1
                else:
                    pBall -= 1
        if pProgress == -28 and pBall in range(pOne - 2, pOne + 2):
            ponger = random.randint(1, 64)
            if pMove == False:
                pMove = True
            elif pMove == True:
                pMove == False
        elif pProgress == 28 and pBall in range(pTwo -2, pTwo + 2):
            ponger = random.randint(1, 64)
            if pMove == False:
                pMove = True
            elif pMove == True:
                pMove == False
        if pProgress == -32:
            pProgress == 0
            pTwoP += 1
        elif pProgress ==  32:
            pProgress == 0
            pOneP += 1
        if pOneP == 5:
            characterRender("A", (255,255,255), 16, 32)
            time.sleep(10)
            pongPlay = False
        if pTwoP == 5:
            characterRender("A", (255,255,255), 48, 32)
            time.sleep(10)
            pongPlay = False

        mainScreen.fill(WHITE, rect=[pixelRasterize(3, True), pixelRasterize(pOne, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, True)])
        mainScreen.fill(WHITE, rect=[pixelRasterize(61, True), pixelRasterize(pTwo, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(5, True)])
        mainScreen.fill(WHITE, rect=[pixelRasterize(pProgress + 32, True), pixelRasterize(pBall, False), pixelRasterize(1, True), pixelRasterize(1, False)])
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1 / 60)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The key constants should be prefixed with `pygame`.

e.g.

`pygame.K_RETURN`

Your import statement read

```
import pygame
```

So all this does is import `pygame` as a module, any members of `pygame` must still be qualified by `pygame.<member>` to be accessible.

If you had written your import statement like

```
from pygame import K_RETURN, K_S, K_W, K_UP, K_DOWN
```

or

```
from pygame import *
```

Then you could use the key constants as you do in the question. The former could get tedious as you imported more things from `pygame`. The later version is considered bad practice as it imports an unknown number of items into your modules global scope.

You also have the advantage of the `pygame.` prefix giving you increased readability, as the origin of that value is clear.

Comment: Great, updated to my GitHub page. Going to see if it works when I go to the location with the Raspberry Pi I'm developing on tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is correct, But I just want to give you an explanation for it so you can hopefully learn from this error and next time you'll know what's up!

```
import pygame
```

Imports the module name pygame but does not enter the names of the functions/classes defined in pygame. You need to use the module name so you can access the functions etc within:

```
pygame.K_RETURN
```

Essentially, you're interpreter knows to check the module pygame for K_RETURN.